# Reverse Proxing with HA Proxy

Tags: ssl, subdomain, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to use HA Proxy as Reverse Proxy for LoadBalancing and Health-Check Purpose mainly.

Therefore, I have to address different domains with several subdomains and/or subpaths.

1. https://sub1.example1.com
2. https://subsub.sub1.example1.com
3. https://sub2.example2.com
4. https://example3.com/path1

Unfortunately, I'm not finding an opportunity to define a frontend for each Domain to bind the SSL-cert-file to.
Additionally, I'm not pretty sure whether HAProxy provides something like ProxyPass to handle the "path"-Stuff.

Can somebody please give me an example how to solve this with HAProxy?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single frontend that handles all of the subdomains and use [ACL's](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/introduction-to-haproxy-acls/) to route to different backends. You define your [certificates](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/haproxy-ssl-termination/) on the `bind` line and multiple can be specified. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the "ProxyPass to handle the "path"-Stuff" but if you provide more detail I can help. HAProxy is extremely flexible.

> provides something like ProxyPass to handle the "path"-Stuff.

Example of how you might handle the multiple subdomains:

```
defaults
    mode http

frontend fe_main
    bind :80
    # define all certificates
    bind :443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/sub1.example.com.pem crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/sub2.example.com.pem crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/example3.com.pem

    use_backend be_sub1 if { req.hdr(host) sub1.example.com }
    use_backend be_sub2 if { req.hdr(host) sub2.example.com }
    default_backend be_catchall

backend be_sub1
    server app1 192.168.1.10:80 check

backend be_sub2
    server app1 10.2.0.4:443 check ssl verify none

backend be_catchall
    server catchall1 10.3.2.5:80 check
```

Comment: First of all, thanks, that helps a lot.
The "Path-Stuff" is meant as a Redirect from https://example3.com/path1 to http://server3.internal whereas (e.g.) https://example3.com should route to http:/server4.internal 

Is there a way to apply the different certificates dynamically? like only giving the folder path instead of each single certificate?

how does HA-Proxy knows which certificate belongs to which domain?

Comment: If you want to use a specific servers or backends for specific paths you would use an ACL combined with either a use_backend rule or a use-server rule (inside of a backend). i.e. use_backend if { path -m beg /path1 } or use-server if { path -m beg /path1 }

Regarding certificates, it is able to match on the SNI sent by the client and produce the appropriate certificate to the client.